# Проблема с PHP/MySQL базами данных, добавлением в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

Не понимаю, почему не добавляется, битый час уже пытаюсь понять.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "test";
    $database = "test_users";

    $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $repeat_password = $_POST['r_password'];

        if ($password == $repeat_password) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO 'users' ('id', 'username', 'login', 'password') VALUES ('', '$username', '$login', '$password')");

            echo "Sucessfully registered!";
        }
        else {
            die('Your password dont active!');
            echo "Not a successfully!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: а вы попробуйте вывести сообщение об ошибке, глядишь и понятнее станет все.

Comment: биндинг параментров используйте. И какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Уверен, что установка плагина xdebug позволит вам выполнить скрипт в отладочном построчном режиме и выяснить причины неисправности. И никогда, никогда не проверяйте, что возвращают вам функции. А то вдруг соединение с базой не установилось или запрос синтаксически не верно составлен. Это же не нужно проверять

Comment: У некоторых версий sql не надо название таблицы в кавычки брать